# Python Shutil Copy Command

Tags: python, shutil

```
shutil.copyfile('configdata[3]+"/"+configdata[4]','configdata[11]+"/"+configdata[4]')
```

While i try to use the above syntax for `shutil.copyfile`, it throws invalid syntax. Please help.

Comment: Maybe you mean `shutil.copyfile(configdata[3]+"/"+configdata[4], configdata[11]+"/"+configdata[4])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off the configdata[i] are variables so you cannot '' the inner item.

Secondly you missed the "+" between configdata 4 and configdata 11 and the single quotes.

So perhaps something like this?

```
shutil.copyfile(configdata[3]+"/"+configdata[4], configdata[11]+"/"+configdata[4])
```

Comment: Can improve OP's code even further by using `os.path.join` instead of adding the slash.